# Android Image not loading correctly in imageview in an activity in real device. But displaying correctly in emulator

Tags: android, image, android-emulator, splash-screen

I have created a logo for my app in android. The logo is in oval shape as given below.

[image]

As you can see that there are no black portions in the logo which I have created using an online editor from internet. I have created a simple splash screen for my app while it starts the app upon tapping the app icon. In the manifest I have given as below in my splash screen actiivity:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Now when I try to run the app on emulator, the logo is displaying as fine in my app splash screen. I will show a screen shot of it below:

[image]

Now when I run this on the real device, the same logo becomes like this:

[image]

How does this happen? There is some black colour alongside the oval shape of the logo. Why is this much difference in the same logo which is shown in both emulator and real device? Can someone suggest me to remove the black colour from the logo.? I didn't find out the black colour portion in the logo image when the logo image is viewed using windows photo viewer. Then how does this black colour comes in real device where as it is invisible in emulator. By the way my emulator is jelly bean version and real device is kitkat version of android.

Comment: Are you using gif image? If yes, switching to png might be inevitable https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62016 .

Comment: But when I tried it on Xperia M, there was no problem with the logo. It has Jelly Bean 4.3 on it...

Comment: Thanks...Your comment helped me out in solving the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the answer, the image which I have used is actually a gif which has been converted from an online website. I used it and just converted into png by renaming the extension to png from gif using another small software on my pc. That was the problem. When I tried saving the image as png itself from the server to my pc, the problem solved.

As stated by harism, I think this is a problem in KitKat (Android 4.4) only. As this problem is not there in other android versions. So if there exists any black portions in your images in your project, then convert the image from gif to png using any software or online editor. Or check this link out..
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62016, which was mentioned by harism.